# What is the probability that, where $S_n$ is the set of the first $n$ primes, all the factors of a number are not in $S_n$?

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $S_n$ be the set of the first $n$ prime numbers and let $s_n$ be the $n$-th prime number. Then, let $K_{n}$ be the set of numbers $\{k\ |\ s_n+1\leq k\leq2s_n^2\}$. What is the probability that an element of $K_n$ has no prime factors in $S_n$?

This can be brute-forced for smaller $n$. For example, let's look at the case where $n=3$. Here, $S_3=\{2,3,5\}$ and $K_3=\{k\ |\ 6\leq k\leq50\}$. We can see easily that the only elements of $K_3$ such that for all $s\in S_3$ and $k\in K_3$, $\gcd(s,k)=1$ are $k=7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,$ and $49$. So, here our probability is $P(X)=\frac{13}{45}=0.2\overline{8}$.

I know through [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate?scrlybrkr=54fa3938) that $P(X)\geq\frac{1}{2s_n^2-s_n}$, but I don't know where to go from there. I will admit that the interval for $K_n$ here is somewhat arbitrary - my initial question was going to be "what's the probability that a random natural number has none of its factors in $S_n$", but I know it can be a bit dodgy when trying to define a so-called "random natural number". Who knows, though, maybe it's easier to say something about this for an arbitrary number instead of a number in th interval. Either way, if anybody has any ideas of what to do, let me know. Thank you!

Comment: If $m$ is large (say larger than $10^5$) and $n$ is a random number much larger than $m$ (say larger than $m^3$) , then the probability that $n$ has no prime divisor smaller than $m$ (and therefore no divisor except $1$ smaller than $m$) is about $\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(m)}$ , where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant. Google rough numbers for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first look at $S_3 = \{2,3,5\}$ for a moment.

The Chinese remainder theorem says that if $1 \le k \le 30$ (where $30= 2\cdot3\cdot5$) then the triple $(k\bmod 2, k \bmod 3, k\bmod 5)$ has every possible value once. The possible values are $(a,b,c)$ where $a \in \{0,1\}$, $b \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $c = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. So choosing a random number $k$ between $1$ and $30$ is equivalent to choosing a random triple $(a,b,c)$. When do we get a $k$ not divisible by $2$, $3$, or $5$? When $a\ne0$, $b\ne0$, and $c\ne0$. This has probability $\frac12$ for $a$, $\frac23$ for $b$, and $\frac45$ for $c$, or $\frac12 \cdot \frac23 \cdot \frac45 = \frac{4}{15}$ overall.

The set of remainders modulo $2$, $3$, and $5$ will be the same for any set of $30$ consecutive integers, giving us the same probability $\frac{4}{15}$. By joining together multiple such sets, we conclude that the probability $\frac{4}{15}$ is the same for any interval whose length is divisible by $30$. When the length is not divisible by $30$, it will still be a good approximation, especially when the interval is large. For your example $K_3 = \{6, 7, \dots, 50\}$, the probability is $\frac{13}{45}$, which is not quite equal to $\frac{4}{15} = \frac{12}{45}$, but it's pretty close.

Generalizing to $S_n = \{p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots, p_n\}$, we can use the same reasoning to get a probability of $$\frac{(p_1-1)(p_2-1)\cdots (p_n-1)}{p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n}$$ for a number randomly chosen from an interval of length $p_1 p_2 \cdots p_n$. This will continue to be a good approximation for any sufficiently long interval.